# Crash when trying to login to QBChat service in android

Tags: android, quickblox

I am using Quickblox for implementing 1:1 chat service. I am successfully able to SignIn, and create a private chat dialog. But when I want to start chat in created private dialog QBChatService gets crashed on the method called QBChatService.getInstance().login(qbUser);.

I am stuck because I don't know why it is saying " User's id and password can't be null." As I am passing id and password to QBUSer object as following:

```
QBUser qbUser = new QBUser("priyanka", "12345678");
QBChatService.getInstance().login(qbUser);`
```

Please suggest where am i doing wrong.

> Following is my crash report:-

```
   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: User's id and password can't be 
     null
        at com.quickblox.chat.QBChatService.validateUser(Unknown Source)
        at com.quickblox.chat.QBChatService.login(Unknown Source)
        at com.quickblox.chat.QBChatService.login(Unknown Source)
        at com.example.android.leavemanagement.fragments.ChatFragment.retrieveDialogById(ChatFragment.java:214)
        at com.example.android.leavemanagement.fragments.ChatFragment.onViewCreated(ChatFragment.java:121)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no constructor of QBUser having userName or Id and Password[image: As per DOC, see this picture]
Hence You should change this below by something else like u can try the last one if you have email id

```
QBUser qbUser = new QBUser("priyanka", "12345678");
```

try like this,

```
qbUser = new QBUser("priyanka");
qbUser.setPassword("12345678")
```

Comment: how should i change it to match 5th constructor in list posted by you?

Comment: do u have email Id of priyankar?, if yes then pass it as third parameter

Comment: Still the same crash.